# Browsers supported by teams page actually talks about SO Talent - mistake in doc

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000054247-teams-technical-requirements

> These browsers are fully supported by Stack Overflow **Talent**
>   (current and one previous stable release only, no developer or beta
>   releases):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.